# Как откатить элемент в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть какой-то элемент(и код к нему):

```html
<button id="MyButton"> что-то </button>
<script>
$('#MyButton').on('click',()=>{$('#MyButton').text('что-то другое')})//jquery
</script>
```

как мне сделать некий бэкап,
что-бы какой-то функцией
откатить элемент на тот момент, когда был произведено сохранение?

```js
function save(element){/*магия*/}
function back(element,saved){/*магия*/}
```

Comment: Про магию это не к программистам. Обратитесь в экстрасенсам и магам пожалуйста.

Comment: Сохраняйте в массив нужные вам свойства объекта, например { text: 'бывший текст' } перед заданием новых. И потом при back берите из массива и прописывайте в элемент обратно. Есть ещё вариант - делать каждый раз клон узла через `element.cloneNode(true)`, а при возврате подменять на него. Но при клоне не все свойства элемента клонируются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#MyButton');
let ctrlZ = document.querySelector('#MyCtrlZ');
let history = [];

button.addEventListener( 'click', ()=>{
  history.push({
    property: 'innerText',
    value: button.innerText,
  });
  button.innerText = `что-то другое ${Date.now()}`;
});

ctrlZ.addEventListener( 'click', ()=>{
  if( !history.length ) return;
  let historyItem = history.pop();
  button[historyItem.property] = historyItem.value;
});
```

```html
<button id="MyButton">Сменить текст этой кнопки</button>
<button id="MyCtrlZ">Ctrl + Z</button>
```